# Addind a previous(back)image button to a gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/screen_background">      


 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout01"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp">



<ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:src="@drawable/tone_movies_banner"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"          
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add a back image Button to above layout xml file?
where can i add this statement

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/back_btn"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_movielist_back"
/>
```

Could any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its totally upto you(your desgin, screen layout) where it should be present. Currently seeing your layout, you can add it above your `LinearLayout`(**id=linearLayout1**).

Plus it would be great if you could reduce the back button height.

```
android:layout_height="19dp" //instead of 190dp.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it after

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/screen_background"> 




 <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/back_btn"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_movielist_back"
/>
```

if you want it on **TOP LEFT Corner** of the screen

or  Replace `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

if you want it on **TOP RIGHT Corner** of the screen

Back button is generally found generally only in these two positions..

Rest it is purely subjective where you find it giving a good look to your app